# Merging TIFF file with other shapefiles to use ArcGIS geoprocessing tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, modelbuilder, geotiff-tiff

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

I have a TIFF file and I already applied the Copy Raster to make it an ESRI grid (i.e. I did not specify any file in the output field).

The problem is, when using ModelBuilder, other geoprocessing tools do not recognize the output of my Copy Raster (except Raster Calculator).

How can I generate a layer or another type of shapefile so that I can use my TIFF file in the different geoprocessing tools?

Comment: where's the code you have 'at least' attempted?

Comment: Which geoprocessing tools specifically are you trying to use? Many of them (e.g. Clip) have a separate version for rasters.

Comment: I think it would be really helpful to have a bit more detail about the goals of your project.  As @Mo already mentioned, what code have you tried already?  What is your input data?  Not just data format, but type, as some Raster data is not conducive to conversion to a non-raster format like a shapefile.  It could be a matter of finding the correct tool to use for your data format as opposed to converting your data.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what tool your Copy Raster tool is feeding into. If you look at the Syntax section of the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000) for the tool. The output is a **Raster Dataset**. Many tools take **Layers** as inputs so without actually seeing your model I suggest you pass the output of the Copy Raster tool into a [Make RasterLayer tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Raster_Layer/00170000006t000000/) then feed that into the downstream tool?